# save dark mode/light mode to localStoage

Tags: javascript, sass, local-storage

I have a dark mode feature. HTML and SCSS and javascript are working properly.

But when I refreshed the page, everything returned to normal, not in dark mode.

I want to save the values ​​of dark mode and light mode to localStorage. but I'm confused, I don't know how. is there anyone can help me? Please help me

I've searched on several searches but it still doesn't work. If you can't answer my question, please don't make this post a similar post. because I've read and implemented it but it doesn't work.

this is my [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/PoNpzWG)

**Mode Switcher HTML**

```
 <div id="modeSwitcher">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
   <label class="label" for="chk">
     <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
     <div class="ball"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
#modeSwitcher{
    margin: 5% 50%;

    .checkbox {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        &:checked + {
            .label {
                .ball {
                    transform: translateX(35px);

                    &::after{
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        background-color: #0A0E27;
                        width: 13px;
                        height: 13px;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                        bottom: 50%;
                        left: -5%;
                        transform: translateY(50%);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .label {
        background-color: #0A0E27;
        border-radius: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        height: 16px;
        width: 50px;
        transform: scale(1.5);

        .fa-moon{
            color:#0A0E27 ;
        }

        .ball {
            background-color: #FDC503;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            left: 3px;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            transform: translateX(0px);
            transition: transform 0.2s linear;
        }
    }
}

body{
  background-color: #fff;
    &.dark{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const check = document.getElementById('chk');

check.addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  localStorage.darkMode=!localStorage.darkMode;
});

window.onload=function() {
  if(localStorage.darkMode) document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify this in css:

```
body.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
body.light {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Modify this in javascript:

```
window.onload=function() {
  if(localStorage.darkMode=="true") {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
    document.getElementById("chk").checked=true;
  }
  else {
    document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  }
};
document.getElementById("chk").addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  document.body.classList.toggle('light');
  localStorage.darkMode=(localStorage.darkMode=="true")?"false":"true";
});
```

Comment: it always goes to dark mode, when I click on the light mode the value is not there

Comment: What "light mode"?  I only see dark mode checkbox.

Comment: We can choose to use light mode or dark mode, i mean

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There is only dark = there is no "light":
If dark is selected, then "light" is not selected.
If dark is not selected, then "light" is selected.
I fail to see what you do not understand...

Comment: You have css body dark.
You don't have css body light.

Comment: Added light mode, checkbox to reflect localStorage, and better behavior for reading/writing localStorage (realized/remembered it's string-based).

Comment: Note: Duplicating tabs (at least in chrome) does NOT call `window.onload` = needs a reload.

Comment: in the code you wrote, when the browser closes and opens the browser again, the previous value is still there? if that's right, adding ```window.onbeforeunload``` will clear the value in localstorage?

Comment: As far as I know: localStorage stays "forever" -
unless removed by command or by browser-level.
Not sure about sessionStorage.

Comment: I tried using sessionStorage, when I refresh the page it was still there (value), when I closed the browser and opened it again, the value was reset. Thank you for helping me :) @iAmOren

Answer (score 1):

You can store data with this line `localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true');`

and you can retrieve with this one `var darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');`

then just apply your style with your own logic

Comment: This doesnt help if you uncheck the checkbox again.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true')` can be shortened to `localStorage.darkMode=true`, and `darkMode=localStorage.getItem('darkMode')` to `darkMode=localStorage.darkMode`.
Notice: before it's defined/saved, `localStorage.getItem('darkMode')` returns `null` - even if not defined(!) and `localStorage.darkMode` returns `undefined`.

Comment: You also populate your checkbox based on this value.