# Dark Mode not working during loading time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a dark mode toggle button which can toggle between dark and light mode on click, User preference is also stored using `localStorage`. The user should manually press the button to toggle to other mode. If the user's choice is dark mode, Every page will be in dark mode and it doesn't turn to light mode on refreshing. Everything looks fine upto now but the real issue comes with loading time. The load time of a page is nearly 1 second and in that time, Page appears to be in light mode even if user's choice is dark mode. I don't want that to happen. I want loading time section in dark mode if user's choice is dark.
This is my current code:

```
<script>
const body = document.querySelector('body');
function toggleDark() {
  if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    body.classList.remove('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
  } else {
    body.classList.add('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
  }
}

if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
  body.classList.add('dark');
}
</script>
<style>
body {background-color: #ffffff}
body.dark {background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff} 
</style>
<button class="dark-mode" id="btn-id" onclick="toggleDark()"></button>
```

Comment: My advice would be not to rely only on the client side for this. You should be able to set the class on the server side. If only the client side is able to add the class you will always have a time during the loading, (while the Javascript is still being loaded / interpreted) where the class is not present. Use cookies so you can check them on the server side too.

Comment: Add your `<script>` as the first line inside `<body>` to help reduce the FOUC

Comment: Take also the [prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) css property into account. For a total introduction into dark mode, I would suggest reading [A Complete Guide to Dark Mode on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/).

Comment: You could add/remove class to the "html" tag (you do this using `document.documentElement.classList` instead) ... that way, your code to set the class to `dark` can be in the head element, before body even exists - you'll need to change `body.dark` to `html.dark body` in the CSS though

Comment: @JaromandaX How about my solution? Too complex? It is all client side and localStorage based

Comment: yeah, so's mine @mplungjan :p and doesn't require adding CSS dynamically :p mine doesn't run here for some reason ... something is insecure about it ... and when I check which line is not secure, it points to code that isn't even mine (it actually pointed to your code!!! though I think that's a debugger malfunction) - that's why I posted a link rather than an answer

Comment: @JaromandaX Localstorage does not run in SO's sandbox

Comment: ahh, that explains it :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Post yours as answer and comment out the localStorage as I did - it is more elegant than mine

Comment: See my post about dark mode here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577939/save-dark-mode-light-mode-to-localstoage

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to load the script in the `<head>` element, and toggle the class on `html` element

To do so, you use `document.documentElement.classList` as that is the `HTML` element

Then change your CSS to

```
html.dark body {}
```

etc .. the class selector on HTML

```css
html body {background-color: #ffffff}
html.dark body {background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff}
```

```html
<script>
  const body = document.querySelector('body');

  function toggleDark() {
    if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
      //localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
      //localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    }
  }

  //if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
  //}
</script>
<button class="dark-mode" id="btn-id" onclick="toggleDark()">DARK</button>
```

> Due to restrictions, `localStorage` is unavailable on stack overflow - uncomment those lines to see it work

Or - see https://jsfiddle.net/e9zg2p4c/

Comment: Nice. Very elegant. Did not consider documentElement

Answer (score 0):

Store it to backend database. Then when serving HTML content put proper class/style for your elements. This will remove flickering between loading times:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Use Less/Sass for better management */
            .theme.light {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
            .theme.dark {
                background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="theme <?= $user->themeName; ?>">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're able to store a user's choice of theme at the backend, why not simply have two (or more) css files - dark.css and light.css for example - and just load the right one in a `link` tag?

Comment: Yes, but it could also be done front end - links can be added as required and/or an existing link with a default scheme could be there and the href value changed if required.

Comment: @ATD "changing link" will require some processing, so it's either JS or Backend. To have two files is also bad idea, because when using Less, you just change variables values for specific class instead of having two different files that must be maintained in tandem.

Comment: @Justinas Which is why I prefer to use the variables method.  But, changing links is relatively straightforward and can be done before `tbody`, it requires just a few lines of code and an ID on the `style` tag so that you can target the `href` attribute.

Comment: @ATD And how will you execute your code while it's being loaded from server?

Comment: @Justinas If the server is generating the entire page before sending it to the user, the appropriate theme is inserted at that point.  If the server outputs the page in the normal way, a `script` tag underneath the `style` tag will be able to access the href attribute immediately as long as there is an `id` attribute set for the `style` tag.  The functionality would be within a normal function block (to allow the user to change themes as well), but the script would include a line underneath this, that is outside of a function block so it calls the function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A little more tricky to toggle AND have a default theme

Note the localStorage calls do not work here at SO

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/L0x7jb5f/)

In the code below replace

`const theme = "dark";` with
`localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light"`

and uncomment `// localStorage.setItem("theme", body.classList.contains("dark") ? "light" : "dark");`

on your server

```css
.dark { background-color: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .theme {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    const theme = "dark"; // localStorage.getItem("theme") || "theme"
    if (theme === "dark") {
      const st = document.createElement("style");
      st.id="darkStyle";
      st.innerText = `body.theme { background-color: black; color: white; }`;
      document.querySelector("head").appendChild(st);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementById("toggleTheme").addEventListener("click", function() {
        const body = document.querySelector("body");      
        const darkStyle = document.getElementById("darkStyle");
        if (darkStyle) {
          darkStyle.remove(); // remove stylesheet now we know what the user wants
          body.classList.remove("theme");
        }  
        const theme = body.classList.contains("theme"); 
        body.classList.toggle('theme',!theme);
        body.classList.toggle('dark',theme);
        // localStorage.setItem("theme", theme ? "light" : "dark"); // uncomment on your server
      });
    })
  </script>



</head>

<body class="theme">
  Here is the body

  <button id="toggleTheme" type="button">Toggle theme</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the only real difference between light and dark is the colours, why not simply create css variables for each colour you are going to use and use javascript to change the values of the variables.  This way, once you have defined the classes using the variables in the appropriate places, changing the variable values changes the classes automatically.  The choice of "dark" and "light" can be stored in whatever way is available to you - localStorage, cookies or backend etc - and you simply set the appropriate colours to the css variables when the page is being loaded.  There's no need for separate definitions for each class and, as a developer, it allows you to quickly test the colour schemes without having to manually change every class one by one.

```js
function changeTheme(t) {
  if (t == "dark") {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--backgroundcolour", "black");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--fontcolour", "white");
  } else {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--backgroundcolour", "white");
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--fontcolour", "black");
  }

}
```

```css
:root {
  --backgroundcolour:black;
  --fontcolour:white;
}

body {
  background-color:var(--backgroundcolour);
  color:var(--fontcolour);
}

span {
  background-color:var(--backgroundcolour);
  color:var(--fontcolour);
}

div {
  background-color:var(--backgroundcolour);
  color:var(--fontcolour);
}

table {
  background-color:var(--backgroundcolour);
  color:var(--fontcolour);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeTheme('dark');">Use dark theme</button><button onclick="changeTheme('light');">Use light theme</button>
<hr>
<span>Text in a span</span>
<hr>
<div>Text in a div</div>
<hr>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Text in a table</td></tr>
  
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: This should be in a STYLE tag in the HEAD part of the document.  As long as code is in place after that, the variables can be changed even before the BODY tag has been loaded.

Comment: yes, so, that's the part that would've helped the OP :p - oh, wait, you did that - sorry I truly misread your code - comments removed

Comment: One thing to note (I was considering a solution with CSS vars too) - this won't work in IE (not that that is a bad thing, the eventual death of Internet Explorer will come from many small cuts)

Comment: We never use IE and have, for quite some time, advised our users not to either.  There are so many quirks in IE, that it became a nightmare to get any consistency across all browsers.  When we have had to take IE into account, the user's choice was stored backend and the page was actually rendered with the right theme in place to start with.  We even went so far as to allow them to pick their own colours and stored those as well.  But we often had to add a linked stylesheet that set the defaults for all element types so we could at least have the same starting point in the main css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use checkbox, this solution for you.

if you want the value to remain unchanged, use `localStorage`. If you want a dark mode where you have values ​​disappear when you close a tab or browser, use `sessionStorage`.

```js
const check = document.getElementById('chk');

check.addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
  localStorage.darkMode=!localStorage.darkMode;
});

window.onload=function() {
  if(localStorage.darkMode) document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
#modeSwitcher{
   margin: 5% 50%;
}

#modeSwitcher .checkbox {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
}

#modeSwitcher .checkbox:checked + .label .ball{
   transform: translateX(35px);
}

#modeSwitcher .checkbox:checked + .label .ball::after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #0A0E27;
   width: 13px;
   height: 13px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   bottom: 50%;
   left: -5%;
   transform: translateY(50%);
}

#modeSwitcher .label {
    background-color: #0A0E27;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
    width: 50px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

#modeSwitcher .label .fa-moon{
    color:#0A0E27 ;
}

#modeSwitcher .label .ball {
    background-color: #FDC503;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

body{
     background-color: #fff;
}

body.dark{
     background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="modeSwitcher">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
   <label class="label" for="chk">
     <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
     <div class="ball"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `window.onload` is far too late to switch themes if you want to avoid 1 second of light mode ... the issue is how to enable dark theme as quickly as possible - OP already has a working switch, it's just not soon enough

Comment: put that script on the ```<head>```

Comment: sure, except, wait, document.body doesn't exist yet - but if you put it in window.onload, it doesn't matter if that's in the head or the body ... it's WAY too late even later than the OP's code